# Android start activity in correct way

Tags: android, android-activity

im new to android dev.
I start by follow some tutorial and i make a simple app.
I'm confused to the way start other `activity`.
I have 3 activity `login`, `main`, `temp`
when i at `main activity` i want to start `temp activity` by the code below:

```
@Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
    int id = item.getItemId();

    Intent nextIntent;
    switch (id){
        case R.id.item1:
            nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TempActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.item2:
            nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TempActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
            break;
        case R.id.item3:
            nextIntent = new Intent(MainActivity.this, TempActivity.class);
            startActivity(nextIntent);
            overridePendingTransition(R.anim.pull_in_right, R.anim.push_out_left);
            break;
    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
}
```

and i did the same in `login activity` but not working:

```
private void login() {
    Log.d(TAG, "Login");

    _loginButton.setEnabled(false);

    //show spinner
    final ProgressDialog progressDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoginActivity.this,
            R.style.AppTheme_Dark_Dialog);
    progressDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
    progressDialog.setMessage("Authenticating...");
    progressDialog.show();

    // TODO: Implement your own authentication logic here.

    new android.os.Handler().postDelayed(
            new Runnable() {
                public void run() {
                    // On complete call either onLoginSuccess or onLoginFailed
                    onLoginSuccess();
                    // onLoginFailed();
                    progressDialog.dismiss();
                }
            }, 3000);
}
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == requestCode) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
            // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
            startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}

public void onLoginSuccess() {
    //do nothing
    finish();
}
```

instead i have to do this:

```
@Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    if (requestCode == requestCode) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            // TODO: Implement successful signup logic here
            // By default we just finish the Activity and log them in automatically
            this.finish();
        }
    }
}

public void onLoginSuccess() {
    startActivity(new Intent(this, MainActivity.class));
    setResult(RESULT_OK);
    finish();
}
```

**and why** `requestCode == requestCode` i couldn't find function `setRequestCode` like `setResultCode`
**last question**: should I use `fragment` instead of `activity` to share my `NavigationBar` because now i have to include `navigationBar` layout to `tempActivity` layout, and same `java code` in class

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firstly No need to use `ProgressDialog` for starting any activity it doesn't take too much of time,  `ProgressDialog` is used for long running operations like server call ,upload/download image etc

Start Activity Simple

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

Thats it nothing more

Now you want to pass data to activity than

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
intent.putExtra("INTENT_PARAM", YourValue);
startActivity(intent);
```

onActivityResult() this method is used when you want to get some data back from the activity you lunching

For this look at this post -https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/4741746

> why requestCode == requestCode i couldn't find function setRequestCode
>   like setResultCode

onActivityResult() method is only called in case of startActivityForResult() and you are calling startActivity ,calls like `startActivityForResult (intent, 100);`  here 100 is requestCode and result code is

```
Intent returnIntent = new Intent();
setResult(Activity.RESULT_CANCELED, returnIntent);
finish();
```

here Activity.RESULT_CANCELED is your resultCode

**Suggestion is call activity like**

```
Intent intent = new Intent(YourCurrentActivity.this, LoginActivity.class);
startActivity(intent);
```

> should I use fragment instead of activity to share my NavigationBar

Yes you can just put this layout in your xml

```
<RelativeLayout
                android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />
```

and to add different fragment

```
public void addYourFragment(){
                YourFragment myFragment = new YourFragment();
                FragmentManager fragmentManager = this.getSupportFragmentManager();
                FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
                fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.fragment_container, myFragment, tagToUniqlyIdentifiedFramgent);
                fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(tagToUniqlyIdentifiedFramgent);
                fragmentTransaction.commit();                       
}
```

call this method in switch

```
switch (id){
        case R.id.item1:
            addYourFragment();
            break;
        case R.id.item2:           
            addYourFragmentTwo()
            break;
        case R.id.item3:
            addYourFragmentThree()
            break;
    }
```

Comment: thanks for response, i used progressDialog because it will connect to server to login

Comment: i set `login` as launch activity how to `startActivityforResult` for it

Comment: Intent i = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, 1);    something like this

Answer (score 0):

you can help from these codes:

```
public class ListActivityExample extends ListActivity {
    static final String[] ACTIVITY_CHOICES = new String[] {
        "Open Website Example",
        "Open Contacts",
        "Open Phone Dialer Example",
        "Search Google Example",
        "Start Voice Command"
    };
    final String searchTerms = "superman";

    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setListAdapter(new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
                android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, ACTIVITY_CHOICES));
        getListView().setChoiceMode(ListView.CHOICE_MODE_SINGLE);
        getListView().setTextFilterEnabled(true);
        getListView().setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener()
        {
            @Override
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1,
                    int arg2, long arg3) {
                switch(arg2) {
                case 0: //opens web browser and navigates to given website
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                            Uri.parse("http://www.android.com/")));
                    break;
                case 1: //opens contacts application to browse contacts
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                           Uri.parse("content://contacts/people/")));
                    break;
                case 2: //opens phone dialer and fills in the given number
                    startActivity(new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW,
                           Uri.parse("tel:12125551212")));
                    break;
                case 3: //search Google for the string
                    Intent intent= new Intent(Intent.ACTION_WEB_SEARCH );
                    intent.putExtra(SearchManager.QUERY, searchTerms);
                    startActivity(intent);
                    break;
                case 4: //starts the voice command
                    startActivity(new
                                    Intent(Intent.ACTION_VOICE_COMMAND));
                    break;
                default: break;
                }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

details in http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1646053&seqNum=3

Comment: i want to asked about why in from `login activity` have to do in difference way to start `main activity`

Comment: @HoàngĐăng, please accept my answer. please or upvote me